# Custom folder browser/upload file dialog

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is: when a user clicks on a button, a folder browser should pop up almost the same way when `<input type="file">` is used. The only difference is that I don't want that "Open" button, I want a button with "Save" as text. See that I'm not looking for a **file saver** in javascript, I just want a dialog that user can navigate inside folders, insert a  file name and click on a button called "Save", so that I can make the file saving server-side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file browser is part of the operating system, not the web page. Sorry.